# Getting the inner hash in Perl

Tags: perl

After spending a lot of time on debugging and understanding the reason for the code behavior, I decided to ask for help. It should be something very basic, but I can't seem to understand the reason why it works (actually does not work) like this. A piece of the code:

```
use Data::Dumper;

my (%p_all,%e_all);
get_e(\%e_all);

my %e_abs = $e_all{"ex_abs"};
my %e = $e_all{"ex"};

print Dumper(\%e_abs);

sub get_e{
   my ($ex_href) = @_;
   my $counter = 5;
   my $exec1 = "ABC";
   my $exec2 = "xyz";
   $ex_href->{"ex_abs"}{$exec1} += $counter;
   $ex_href->{"ex"}{$exec2} += $counter;
}
```

Output:

```
$VAR1 = {                                                        
      'HASH(0x9e2a20)' => undef    
};
```

If Ill try to do:

```
my %e_abs = %{$e_all{"ex_abs"}};
```

It will fail with the following error:

```
can't use an undefined value as a HASH reference
```

How can I solve this issue?

Comment: "*It will fail with the following error*" - no, it won't. It runs fine.

Answer (score 4):

`$e_all{ex_abs}` contains a hash *reference*, to assign it to a hash, you first need to *dereference* it:

```
my %e_abs = %{ $e_all{"ex_abs"} };
my %e = %{ $e_all{"ex"} };
```

Or, in more recent Perl versions,

```
my %e_abs = $e_all{"ex_abs"}->%*;
my %e = $e_all{"ex"}->%*;
```

It outputs

```
$VAR1 = {
          'ABC' => 5
        };
```

It won't fail with "Can't use an undefined value..." unless `$e_all{ex_abs}` is undefined.

Note that with [warnings](http://p3rl.org/warnings) on, Perl also tells me

```
Reference found where even-sized list expected at 1.pl line 10.
Reference found where even-sized list expected at 1.pl line 11.
```

Comment: you could demonstrate how to just use the hash reference instead of copying the referred-to hash

Comment: Yeah, but you wouldn't want to make a copy of the hash like that. `my $e_abs = $e_all{"ex_abs"};` is a much better solution.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Is there a better/cleaner/more-good-looking way of: `%e_abs= %{$e_all{"ex_abs"}} if(defined($e_all{"ex_abs"}));`?

Comment: @TTaJTa4: `%e_abs= %{ $e_all{"ex_abs"} || {} };` maybe?

Answer (score 3):

Always use `use strict; use warnings qw( all );`; it would have identified the problem.

```
Reference found where even-sized list expected at a.pl line 6.
Reference found where even-sized list expected at a.pl line 7.
```

Hash values can only be scalars, so you should be using the following:

```
my $e_abs = $e_all{ex_abs};
my $e     = $e_all{ex};

print Dumper($e_abs);
```

Alternatively, you could allocate a hash and copy the keys and values from the old hash into the new one, but that's needlessly expensive. This would be done as follows:

```
my %e_abs = %{ $e_all{ex_abs} };
```